# How to login to a Facebook account from a Flex app?

Tags: apache-flex, facebook

I would like to supply an username(mail address) and password to an API method and login to Facebook. Is it possible with the special swc library to access the API in this manner? If not, can you give me some hints on how to do it using ExternalInterface and JS?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

there is a library called [actionscript facebook api](http://code.google.com/p/facebook-actionscript-api/), it is hosted on google code.
The last time I have used it was to run an example for my students and it worked but it was about 4-5 months ago.

** from just browsing around over there again I saw it was updated and they have examples posted.
I think this will help you.

Comment: That's true, I'm using that library and I've also looked at the examples. However, I can't find the functionality I need in the API.

Answer (score 0):

You will want to use the com.facebook.utils.FacebookSessionUtil to login.

Here is some [code examples](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/facebook/samples/index.html) on how to achieve what you are wanting.